# How to Schedule a firebase functions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

The function as created using either the **HTTPS or the PubSub trigger won't run using the firebase scheduler.**

```
exports.helloworld = functions.https.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRequest((req, res) =>{

   res.send("Hello World Ozone Here");
```

functions.https.schedule is not a function

Comment: Have you tried to update `firebase-functions`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the functions. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions .

> ```
> export scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
>   console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
> });
> ```